# Generic ServiceCaller class

Tags: c#, generics, channelfactory

I have a generic class to create a channel factory from a interface and a another class for call a service method :

```
public class ServiceCaller<T>
{
    public static T GetInstance()
    {   
        //ServiceManager is a generic class for create a ChannelFactory
        ServiceManager<T> channel = new ServiceManager<T>();

        return channel.InnerChannel;
    }
}
```

And I use this :

```
var response = ServiceCaller<TempConvertSoap>.GetInstance().CelsiusToFahrenheit("2");
```

How to do this without `GetInstance` method an directly do :

```
var response = ServiceCaller<TempConverSoap>.CelsiusToFahrenheit("2");
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want make `CelsiusToFahrenheit` method to be static method in generic class `ServiceCaller<TempConverSoap>`? For that you cannot use interface and you need to manually write name of the method to be same as `TempConvertSoap.CelsiusToFahrenheit`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but only if you include the function in `ServiceCaller`. There is no way you can have a constructor create something other than the class instance you're in.

```
public class ServiceCaller<T>
{
    public static string CelsiusToFahrenheit(string val)
    {   
        ServiceManager<T> channel = new ServiceManager<T>();
        return channel.InnerChannel.CelsiusToFahrenheit(val);
    }
}
```